# Is a local PHP include() file cached?

Tags: php, caching, include

After doing some research i'm struggling to find a definitive answer on how and if a PHP `include()` file is cached.

The closest i've found is [here](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/php-cache-includes-61074.html) but it doesn't quite make sense to me.

I have several methods that use other methods from different files and I want to avoid placing include()'s just at the top of the file but i'm not sure how this might affect performance.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is an interpreted language. The default PHP runtime compiles PHP sourcecode to an intermediate representation called PHP bytecode which is then executed. A bytecode cache stores this compiled representation of PHP sourcecode in shared memory. This eliminates the need to load and compile sourcecode on each request which leads to a significant increase in performance (up to 70% more requests per second).

The basic idea, when executing a PHP script is in two steps:

- First: the PHP code, written in plain-text, is **compiled to opcodes**
- Then: those **opcodes are executed**.
  When you have one PHP script, as long as it is not modified, the opcodes will always be the same ; so, doing the compilation phase each time that script is to be executed is kind of a waste of CPU-time.

To prevent that redundant-compilation, there are some opcode caching mechanism that you can use.

Once the PHP script has been compiled to opcodes, those will be kept in RAM -- and directly used from memory the next time the script is to be executed ; preventing the compilation from being done again and again.

**Read more**

- https://blog.graphiq.com/500x-faster-caching-than-redis-memcache-apc-in-php-hhvm-dcd26e8447ad#.tsokdw9d4
- https://github.com/TerryE/opcache/wiki/The-Zend-Engine-and-opcode-caching#opcode-caching-with-opcache
- https://juokaz.com/blog/from-php-to-machine-code

Comment: Thanks for the response. How does that pertain specifically to `include()`. If I `include()` the same file in multiple methods will it only perform the `include()` once and then pull in the compiled code from then on?

Comment: The bytecode is cached in memory, but with an index of the filename; You still need the `include` to tell PHP what code to include... it will then look to see if the bytecode for that file is in the opcode cache, or if it has to retrieve the file from disk

Comment: If you are writing OO code, and want to avoid writing all those incudes, then PHP provides an autoloader

Comment: thanks @MarkBaker the autoloader works perfectly. I wasn't aware of this.